# Can a small signal BJT handle small currents of reverse voltage (Vce) for a short time?

Tags: bjt

I have this piece of circuit with a 12V supply.  I think it will work better in my application without the reverse diode. Do you think it can handle the reverse voltage of C8 that remains charged for a minute or so until it is discharged through the resistors?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you want to remove D13?

Comment: You can't have 8mA of _any_ voltage -- amps are amps and volts are volts.  Could you _edit your title_ to say what you mean?

Comment: In what way will it be reversed? The copious emitter diodes suggest R55 limits current, and C-B junction is just a plain old diode in that case, limited only by temperature rise and absolute ratings.

Comment: Yes, I want to remove D12... When the power supply goes OFF the transistor will have its emitter to a lower voltage than the colector, because C8 remains charged for a little time...

Comment: Please correct your title. "8mA of reverse voltage" really does not make any sense.

Comment: "Yes, I want to remove D12" - there is no D12 in your schematic.

Comment: if you have 8 mA flowing  into the collector of that transistor you have much larger problems,  with 800V across R55: C23 and/or C8 is going to be unhappy.  Realistically D16 can only stand off about 400V, but still the numbers are not going to work.

Comment: if the reverse bias is only 12V the current into the collector will be single digit microamperes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D16 prevents any reverse current through the emitter. As a result, Q2 essentially becomes a plain diode from collector to base during this reverse discharging operation. This is completely fine and D13 can be safely removed.

In general though, don't trust LTspice on this reverse bias behavior. It doesn't account for B-E reverse breakdown.

Answer (score 0):

Q2 is safe because prospective currents are very low. C8 is not safe so you could put a reverse 1N4148 diode across it or use a MLC cap.

Comment: In which scenario do you anticipate a reverse voltage over C8?